# Can index.php take over for front-page.php in template hierarchy on second page?

Tags: templates, pagination, frontpage

I'm confused by the template hierarchy in WordPress. I have `front-page.php` in a theme I'm developing. It looks great and it works, but then when a user clicks 'Older Posts', it just shows the same content as before, but the URL is changed to ?paged=2.

Looking at the diagram about Template Hierarchy on [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), since the second page is *not* the front page, I'd expect it to fall through `front-page.php` to either `home.php` or `index.php`, but it's not doing that; it's just loading `front-page.php` over and over again.

So how can I load, say `index.php`, for every page other than the front page?

And also, am I crazy for expecting what I expect?

The second question might be subjective. Please only answer the first if you think I am crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination does not affect the template usually, `paged.php` is the exception but not of interest for your question.

To style the first page differently than later pages check for

```
if ( is_front_page() and 1 < get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) 
{ 
    // code for later pages
}
```

Comment: That's...rather hacky. I'd really like to have my "lists of posts" pages to look the same regardless where they are in the site. I.e. working off the same template. Doing what you suggest means the same code is in two spots. Yuck. Is there no other way?

Comment: @ageektrapped - use a [template part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) for code reuse.

Comment: Thanks @Milo. I used your suggestion combined with toscho's to get what I wanted. *Still* think it's weird, but can't do much about it.

Comment: @ageektrapped - you may also want to check out the template filters, which will let you force specific templates under your own conditions. look in `wp-includes/template-loader.php` and `wp-includes/template.php` to see how WordPress selects a template, and the `apply_filters` calls for each where you could add your own filter function to manipulate it.